# Mongo Query Returning Empty Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm a total beginner at this and am using a tutorial to learn the basics of the MEAN stack. I am trying to return the documnents in my database to a web page but am instead receiving an empty array.

I have created a cluster on Mongodb Atlas called mytasklist. Inside here I created a database called mytasklistdb. Inside this I have a table (object) called mytasklistdb.mytasklisttutorial. My understanding of this is limited and so maybe I'm making a huge error somewhere here. I have experience of SQL but not Mongo and so the whole 'clusters' and 'collections'  thing is new to me.

Anyway my code is as follows. I took the string for the database connection from the Mongo connection tab.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('mongodb+srv://myusername:mypassword@mytasklist-qx0ka.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority', ['mytasklisttutorial']);

router.get('/tasks', function(req, res, next){
    db.mytasklistdb.find(function(err, tasks){
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(tasks);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

My database objects look like this:

```
_id:5db5f1f31c9d440000c3e7fe
title:"Walk the dog"    -   this is a string
isDone:false      -     this is boolean
```

I'm just getting an empty array but in the tutorial the guy is getting these 'documents'. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I realised that the 'tasks' part of the tutorial example was relating to a database called 'tasks'. Mine is called 'mytasklistdb'. I therefore changed this. I also added a parameter with the name of my collection to the line passed in to mongojs.

I have changed my code above to reflect this

Comment: can you share the video link and can you update question with your db schema ?

Comment: Do you have collection named `tasks` in the db. If yes you are not passing it as second parameter to the connection constructor. OR before the queries `const collection = db.collection('tasks');` then do `db.collection.find(...)`

Comment: ambianBeing I have added these things - I think you were right but it still doesn't work

Comment: @user1480135 I think there is 1 more change that you need to do. the URL is connecting to a db called `test` which i suppose is not correct. Change the URL to something like: `mongojs('mongodb+srv://myusername:mypassword@mytasklist-qx0ka.mongodb.net/mytasklistdb?retryWrites=true&w=majority', ['mytasklisttutorial']);` If the db name is `mytasklistdb` and collection is `mytasklisttutorial`

Comment: Perfect that works thanks

Comment: @user1480135 you should repost this as an answer.

Comment: It won't let me. It just says I can't do that until 22 hours which never seem to pass

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to replace 'task' and 'test' with the name of my db. As follows:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('mongodb+srv://James:Noentry1@mytasklist-qx0ka.mongodb.net/mytasklistdb?retryWrites=true&w=majority', ['mytasklisttutorial']);

router.get('/tasks', function(req, res, next){
    db.mytasklisttutorial.find(function(err, tasks){
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(tasks);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are not passing your query, just the callback in the find() method, probably you need to do something like this:

```
db.tasks.find({},function(err, tasks){
    if(err){
        res.send(err);
    }
    res.json(tasks);
});
```

Comment: It's still empty unfortunately.